# Signal without any default action except SIGINFO

Tags: linux, signals

Is there any signal with no default action except `SIGINFO`. This [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) suggests that even `SIGPWR` default's action is to terminate the process. My requirement is to handle the signal only when there is a custom signal handler present, otherwise ignore the signal.

Comment: What exactly is your use-case? And what do you mean by `handle the signal only when there is a custom signal handler present`?

Comment: I meant that the default action of the signal should be to nothing, only when there is a signal handler, should the signal do something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `man 7 signal` for a list of all signals and their default dispositions.  Currently I see these as being ignored by default:

```
   Signal     Value     Action   Comment
   ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   SIGCHLD    20,17,18    Ign    Child stopped or terminated
   SIGURG     16,23,21    Ign    Urgent condition on socket (4.2BSD)
   SIGWINCH   28,28,20    Ign    Window resize signal (4.3BSD, Sun)
```

As you can see, there are really not many choices.  I would say that of the above, `SIGCHLD` might be OK if you are sure you have no child processes, or `SIGURG` if you are sure you have no sockets which might be signaled that way.  Finally, `SIGWINCH` is only appropriate if you are sure your program will not have a controlling terminal which could be resized.